# Using [bp] causes malfunctions and improper behaviour in assembly. How to replace addressing with [bp]?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

I have the code below. I load my graphical object data from Object1 in MorphLoop function. This function is absolutely essential for loading my object, however on the other hand it absolutelly 'messes up' everything for the rest of the code, meaning that after my graphical object is successfully displayed I cannot do very basic things in assembly like regular video memory page addressing and things like this.
However if I delete Morphloop function then the graphical object doesn't display properly but my basic assembly routines work as expected (further graphics and music).

So I've been working on two solutions here:

1.:

I'd like to either save bp at the beginning of my code -> display the graphical object -> and then restore the bp register in order to work with my very basic basic assembly instructions as usual (display further graphics and play music).

Or 2.:

I'd like to refactor the equivalent of MorphLoop function. Is it possible to replace bp register in this case?

In one sentence: should I save/load bp in this case or replace bp (refactor MorphLoop)? If so: how to refactor MorphLoop without bp?

```
 org 100h

    section .text
    ;  ...    
    ;  ...
        mov bx,si
        shr bx,2
        shl bx,1
        mov bx,[bx]
        sar bx,1
        add bx,128
        xor bh,bh
        mov bp,Object1
    
    
        mov cx,28
    MorphLoop:
        mov al,[bp]
        sub al,[bp+28]
        cbw
        imul bx
        sar ax,8
        add al,[bp+28]
        mov [bp+28*2],al
        inc bp
        loop MorphLoop
    ;[display graphical object]

    ;[further graphics and music goes here]

    ret 


    section .data
    Object1 db  -20,13
            db  -15,17
            db  -10,20
            db  -7,22
            db  -5,23
            db  5,25
            db  10,53
            db  15,18
            db  0,10
            db  25,2
            db  30,2
            db  33,17
            db  35,20
            db  0,30
```

Comment: 1. Use a different pointer register, such as `di` in a `[bp + di + ...]` addressing mode, or 2. just set up a pointer with `lea di, [bp + ...]` then operate on that register only (add `ss:` prefixes if needed), or 3. `push bp` followed by a later `pop bp` to preserve the value.

Comment: Don't spam tags for other assemblers.  This looks like NASM code, not MASM or TASM.

Comment: Are you mixing assembly with C code? If yes: Most C compilers also require `bx` (and `si` and `di`) not to be modified, so you also have to save these registers using `push` if you use them.

Answer (score 0):

Old school assembler, old school solution:

```
        push bp
        mov bp,Object1
        
        mov cx,28
MorphLoop:
        ;...
        loop MorphLoop
        pop bp
```

`bp` is pushed onto the stack before being assigned to and popped after.

It is far more normal to save/restore all registers that will be clobbered at beginning/end of functions but with the other `;...` lines I'm not certain of being able to do that but I'm reasonably certain of this.